# How to validate form input with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with more than 10 input/select options but i wish to show most of this form inputs when 4 of my fields specifically are filled.

I've done some research and found

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
  // do my things here...
});
```

but this has 2 issues:

1. It doesn't work when i fill inputs
2. One of my fields is select option and here only tries to get inputs

## Code

```js
$(function() {
  // show choices DIV only if all fields are filled.
  $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
      $('.choices').show();
    } else {
      $('.choices').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<form action="" method="POST">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="sm-form-design">
          <input id="seq_no" type="text" class="form-control" name="seq_no" required>
          <label for="seq_no" class="control-label">Seq No.</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="sm-form-design">
          <input id="question" type="text" class="form-control" name="question" required>
          <label for="question" class="control-label">Question</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 sm-form-design">
      <select name="type" id="type" class="form-control">
        <option value="dropdown">Dropdown</option>
        <option value="multiple">Multiple</option>
        <option value="radio">Radio Buttons</option>
        <option value="input">Input</option>
      </select>
      <label for="type" class="control-label">Type</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="sm-form-design">
          <input type="text" name="quiz_time" class="form-control" id="masked-input-time" required>
          <label for="quiz_time" class="control-label">Time *</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- show this part when all fields above are filled -->
  <div class="row choices">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h5>Choices:</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

## Question

How can I validate all my first 4 fields before showing rest of the form?

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Shiladitya's answer works, and is closest to your own code, I find it cleaner to handle forms by serializing data into an object as input occurs. This allows you to more easily reason about validation, as you only have to validate an object, not DOM elements.

Here is a pared down example:

```js
$(function() {
  const formData = {}
  const $form = $('#form-a')
  const $partTwo = $('#part-2')
  
  // some real validation here
  const isValidPartOne = data =>
    data.a && data.b && data.c
  
  const showPartTwo = () => $partTwo.show()

  $form.on('input', ({target}) => {
    formData[target.name] = target.value
    
    // form data is available at all times
    console.log('formData =', formData)

    if (isValidPartOne(formData)) {
      showPartTwo()
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form-a">
  <div id="part-1">
    PART 1
    <input name="a" />
    <input name="b" />
    <select name="c">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose One</option>
      <option value="a">A</option>
      <option value="b">B</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <div id="part-2" style="display:none;">
    PART 2
    <input name="d" />
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: thanks, i tried your code here when i remove my inputs from `PART 1` part two still remains in screen can we hide it in that situation?

Comment: @mafortis yea, if you want to hide it when part1 is no longer valid, you can add that as an else to the `if (isValidPartOne(formData))` conditional.

Comment: thanks, this is much cleaner however i still have issue with my time input and can't include it to validation

Comment: Hey @mafortis were you able to solve the problem you had? Here is a fiddle with the same code (slightly tweaked) matching the HTML you provided: https://jsfiddle.net/fzhqvo8u/ . I don't see any problem on a surface level with validating each field. Is there a specific problem you're running into?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$(function() {

  $('.choices').hide();

  // show choices DIV only if all fields are filled.
  $('select').change(function() {
    validateInput();
  });
  
  $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
    validateInput();
  });
  
  function validateInput() {
   var valid = true;
    $('input[type="text"], select').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() === "") {
        valid = false;
      }
    });

    if (valid) {
     $('.choices').show();
    } else {
     $('.choices').hide();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<form action="" method="POST">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="sm-form-design">
          <input id="seq_no" type="text" class="form-control" name="seq_no" required>
          <label for="seq_no" class="control-label">Seq No.</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="sm-form-design">
          <input id="question" type="text" class="form-control" name="question" required>
          <label for="question" class="control-label">Question</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 sm-form-design">
      <select name="type" id="type" class="form-control">
        <option value="dropdown">Dropdown</option>
        <option value="multiple">Multiple</option>
        <option value="radio">Radio Buttons</option>
        <option value="input">Input</option>
      </select>
      <label for="type" class="control-label">Type</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="sm-form-design">
          <input type="text" name="quiz_time" class="form-control" id="masked-input-time" required>
          <label for="quiz_time" class="control-label">Time *</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- show this part when all fields above are filled -->
  <div class="row choices">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h5>Choices:</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

OnChange of any input, please iterate through all the inputs just to check  whether each input is empty or has value.

Here you go with a solution for your problem 1 that you mentioned in the comment box

```
$(function() {

  $('.choices').hide();

  // show choices DIV only if all fields are filled.
  $('select').change(function() {
    validateInput();
  });

  $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
    validateInput();
  });

  // --- Whenever you make an action you can call this method to validate your inputs ----
  function validateInput() {
    var valid = true;
    $('input[type="text"], select').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() === "") {
        valid = false;
      }
    });

    if (valid) {
      $('.choices').show();
    } else {
      $('.choices').hide();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: `'input[type="text"]'` Doesn't this still only check the text type inputs and not the select type input?

Comment: Thanks but it has 2 minor bugs. `1` when i fill inputs or clear them it requires clicking outside of the field in order to change status of `valid` variable and show or hide choices div `2` as soon as I open dropdown (not selected any option yet) it changes status of `valid` variable.

Comment: For the `problem 1` is will provide a reusable code which will help you to solve

Comment: @Shiladitya not yet bro, still same behavior as before (requires click outside of fields)

Comment: @mafortis When you click outside of the field just call that `validateInput` method

Comment: yes but the bug is the same it requires click in order to show or hide choices, what i'm looking for is some sort of value check, so if input has value show if value is null hide (on typing...)

Comment: @mafortis got the problem and solved as well, please check now

Comment: thanks I just tested your update and here i screen record the results https://www.loom.com/share/28a30c87920747679276f7381c2aa8da

Comment: @mafortis But the same I'm not able to replicate here in stackoverflow

Comment: have you watched the video? the issues i tried to show you was after i removed my time input `choices` still remained and another one was `select` option wasn't include validation only my 3 inputs and then i could see `choices div`

Comment: Yes I saw the video. But my point here is I'm unable to replicate the scenario in StackOverflow. Did you find the same scenario here as well in StackOverflow? Because you might be using something extra which is not present here. Can you check the input type for you timer

Comment: my timer input uses id of `masked-input-time` which using this package https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput

Comment: anyway if we ignore the time input and let say is issue by time picker package, why select option is opt-out of validation?

Comment: In that scenario you need to valid makedInput separately, because it's a wrapper on top of you native input .

Comment: @mafortis select option is not out of the validation, it's there but the implementation is different from input text. you need to understand a difference between an textbox and dropdown.

Comment: I do understand select option difference and i understand you provided `onChange()` for select option but it doesn't fire. `see the screenshot please` https://prnt.sc/rjf0zs

Answer (score 0):

I am not in a place to properly test but looking at your function I would make the following changes,

```
$(function() {
  // show choices DIV only if all fields are filled.
  var flag = false
  $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
      flag = true
    } else {
      flag = false
    }
  });
  if (flag) {
     $('.choices').show();
  } else {
     $('.choices').hide();
  }
});
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
  // call function
});
$('input[type="text"]').keydown(function() {
  // call function
});
```

Comment: sorry i'm confused a bit, we have `each` as well as `keyup` and `keydown` properties, why is that?

Comment: .each simply iterates over items in an array and will not listen for when inputs have changes, using the combination of keyup and keydown to call the function will ensure that when users are typing or using the delete key the function will also get called and calculate whether the other inputs should be shown