# Add URL Validation to TagsInput

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I have an input field where the user is required to enter a link (URL). However, at the moment this field does not have any validation, so the user can enter any nonsense.

So far, I don't need any complex regex.

regex = = /^(ftp|http|https)://[^ "]+$/; is enough for me

However, my problem is that I don't know how to put this expression in my code. I would like that if the entered data does not pass validation, a notification pops up to the user about this.

Thus, at the moment, the input field accepts any string, but I would like it to accept only the URL, and if it is not a URL, then give a small message about it

Please tell me how can I get this result.

```
export default function TagsInputLink(props) {
    const tags = props.tags
    const setTags = props.setTags
    const [input, setInput] = React.useState('');

    const onChange = (e) => {
        const { value } = e.target;
        setInput(value);
    };

    const onKeyDown = (e) => {
        const { key } = e;
        const trimmedInput = input.trim();

        if ((key === 'Enter') && trimmedInput.length && !tags.includes(trimmedInput)) {
            e.preventDefault();
            setTags(prevState => [...prevState, trimmedInput]);
            setInput('');
        }
    };

    const deleteTag = (index) => {
        setTags(prevState => prevState.filter((tag, i) => i !== index))
    }

    return (
        <div className={classes.container}>
            {tags.map((tag, index) => <div className={classes.tag}>
                <ClearIcon className={classes.del} fontSize="big" onClick={() => deleteTag(index)} />
                {tag}
            </div>
            )}
            <input
                className={classes.input}
                value={input}
                placeholder={props.inputPlaceholder}
                onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
                onChange={onChange}
            />
        </div>);
}
```

Comment: You can search the internet for *How to validate form with javascript* - find a tutorial that suits your skill level.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate form input with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60768717/how-to-validate-form-input-with-javascript)

Comment: You could use `<input type="url">` or `<input pattern="^(ftp|http|https)://[^ "]+$">`

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan Unfortunately none of these options work.

Comment: What if `onChange`, you use `if (/^(?:f|ht?)(?:t(?:ps?(?::(?:\/(?:\/\S*)?)?)?)?)?$/.test(value)) { setInput(value); }`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the answer. Yes, it works, but there are two caveats:
1. If you want to delete the entire line, the first letter "h" from the URL always remains undeleted. It cannot be removed.
2. The form accepts values such as "ht", "http", etc

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: So you want final, on-submit validation? Not live input validation?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement it only with `onChange` holding the validity state like below.

```js
const {useState, useMemo} = React;

function URLInput() {
  const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(true);
  
  const style = useMemo(() => {
    return {border: `2px solid ${isValid ? "green" : "red"}`};
  }, [isValid]);
  
  const onChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value) {
      setIsValid(() => /^(ftp|https?):\/\/[^ "]+$/.test(e.target.value));
    } else {
      setIsValid(true);
    }
  }

  return <input onChange={onChange} style={style}/>;
}

function App() {
  return <URLInput/>;
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But it doesn't work with my code. (the field does not allow entering data). Could you provide an example with my code? (in the condition there is a link to the sandbox)

Comment: I have added a message if the input is invalid: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-mountain-jdp8tp

Comment: Yes, I saw it, thanks. But in this case, incorrect results are still passed to the tag. And it is necessary for me that not correct results in a tag could not get. So that tags are formed only from valid results

Comment: What have you inputted that should not be a passed?

Comment: If the user enters an invalid result, then it should not be passed. That is, if the inscription "Invalid URL" is on, the result should not be transmitted. At the moment, the result is transmitted in any case - it is valid or not

Comment: For that, you should have a `<form>` for handling the submit and use the inputted value after checking the validity. Please check the above-shared link again.

Comment: Yes, the result is output to the console. But it doesn't show up in the tags. It is required to me that the valid result would be displayed in tags.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-mountain-jdp8tp